# Docker python:3.9.10-slim-buster image can not install backports.zoneinfo using pip

Tags: python, linux, alpine-linux

I have tried Containerising an django project. I was using `python:alpine` image. The app needed backports.zoneinfo to be installed as requirement. While running  `pip install -r requirements.txt` its showing error when it try to install the `backports.zoneinfo`.

**requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.5.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
Django==4.0.2
sqlparse==0.4.2
```

Then I have opened docker container in interactive mode and tried `pip install backports.zoneinfo`. There also its showing same error.

I have tried the same commands in python:3.9.10 image. It was working fine and the package got installed. This error can be reproduced using any of slim, alpine images.

I have went through couple of fixes. But it wasn't working. Few of the fixes that I have tried are given below. I have tried these inside the container.

- pip upgrade
- pip upgrade wheel
- apt/apk install gcc
- apt/apk install gzdata
- pip install python-dev-tools
- apt/apk install gcc-c++

**To reproduce the error**

**Command**

1. `docker pull python:alpine`
2. `docker run -it python:alpine sh`
3. `pip install backports.zoneinfo`

**Error**

```
Collecting backports.zoneinfo
  Downloading backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.tar.gz (74 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 74 kB 692 kB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: backports.zoneinfo
  Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (PEP 517) ... error
```

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmprpnblifv
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tese9bhy/backports-zoneinfo_cf483b65d8814b8c8a8db93a7369c0cf
  Complete output (35 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/backports
  copying src/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/backports
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_zoneinfo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/backports/zoneinfo
  running egg_info
  writing src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
  warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_output'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
  writing manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/backports/zoneinfo
  running build_ext
  building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/lib
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
  error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's complaining about a missing file or directory. It's a bit misleading since it's `gcc` that's missing. In alpine, you'll also have to install `musl-dev`, too, to get all the required development files.

```
apk add -u gcc musl-dev
```

Also, `python:alpine3.15` is using `python3.10` which doesn't seem to be supported by `backports.zoneinfo`. https://github.com/pganssle/zoneinfo/issues/111

Comment: I have tried the above fix in both python:alpine3.15 and python:3.9.10-slim-buster images.

It was working in slim buster but it didn't worked on alpine image. Also It only worked in slim buster after `apt update && apt install gcc`

I am happy with slim buster image since it is comparatively small. 

Thanks for looking into this buddy.

Comment: @Harikrishnan.A.S-, I've updated my answer to include how to fix it in alpine. I wrote my original answer on the phone, but I've now tried it out on `python:3.8-alpine` and can confirm it's working.

Comment: thanks a lot for looking into this.

the above fix is working. and also I totally forgot to check my python version. I was using python 3.8 in my Ubuntu where I am using python 3.10.2 in my windows. This caused some confusion. I have tried with a fresh `requirements.txt` from python 3.10.2 and its working fine, where `backports.zoneinfo` is not present instead its using `tzdata`. 

Thanks mate for your helping hand. Cheers

Comment: It has been tested on alpine with python3.8 and works perfect!